# Streaming FASTAPI websocket to frontend <video> component

Tags: python, typescript

This is my FASTAPI backend, taking in an mp4 file and streaming it in chunks to the frontend (React)

```py
@app.websocket("/video_stream")
async def video_stream(websocket: WebSocket):
    
    await websocket.accept()

    with open("/Users/yikuang/Documents/infiniwell/mediaserver/example.mp4", "rb") as video_file:
        while True:
            chunk = video_file.read(1024)  # Read a chunk of the video file
            if not chunk:
                break
            await websocket.send_bytes(chunk)
```

On my frontend:

```js
import * as React from "react";

export default function VideoStream() {
  const [stream, setStream] = React.useState<string>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/video_stream");
    const chunks: Blob[] = [];

    socket.onmessage = (event) => {
      if (event.data instanceof Blob) {
        chunks.push(event.data);

        // Create a Blob from accumulated chunks
        const videoBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "video/mp4" });

        // Create an object URL for the Blob
        const videoURL: string = URL.createObjectURL(videoBlob);

        console.log(videoURL);

        setStream(videoURL);
      }
    };

    return () => {
      socket.close();
      chunks.length = 0;
      setStream(undefined);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <video width="640" height="480" controls>
        <source src={stream} type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    </div>
  );
}
```

however, my video component is empty (screenshot attached).

The blobs are being read (as checked by the console.log) but when i open the blob url, the same thing happens, the video does not load and it is an empty video screen. what am i doing wrong here?

to have the video play for me in the component